# Adjusting gap between time and date on 18.04 lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, css

I would like to move the time and date lines closer on the lock screen, but I couldn't find a right parameter to use. I attached the relevant part of my `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` for your reference. The only things that I have changed are the font and size for the time. I thought this should be a easy task but somehow couldn't find a good solution after an hour :( Thanks in advance.

~ Yen-Yung

```
.screen-shield-clock {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em; }

.screen-shield-clock-time {
  font-family: AnjaliOldLipi;
  font-size: 72pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.screen-shield-clock-date {
  font-size: 28pt;
  font-weight: normal; }
```